# Segmentation fault when exiting PyQT app

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqtgraph

First, I have tried my best to find a solution to this problem here and other places and I am have a general idea of what the problem is, but it is not clear to me how to solve it.

The basic problem is that I am getting a segmentation fault when I close my app by pressing the standard "x" button.

The most important details (I think) are that I am using MacOS Sierra, python 3.5.2, and pyqt5.

The app I am building is very loosely based on another project ([Dioptas](https://github.com/Dioptas/Dioptas)), which is a relatively mature project. I am more or less getting started.

When I close the window, the terminal prints out as instructed in MainController.close_event():

```
> here
> closed
> accepted
> Segmentation fault: 11
```

I have tried many of the suggestions online and I am fairly sure that this is due to python not closing all of the windows (perhaps due to the order in which they are being closed - QApplication.CloseAllWindows() says they are closed in a random order, for one thing).  If anyone has a suggestion or solution I would really appreciate it.

The following is my code:

```
import sys
import pyqtgraph as pg
import numpy as np
from PIL import Image
from PyQt5.QtCore import *
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *

class MainController(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__
        self.start()
        self.create_signals()

    def start(self):
        self.widget = MainWidget()
        self.widget.show()

    def create_signals(self):
        self.widget.closeEvent = self.close_event

    def close_event(self, ev):
        print("here")
        QApplication.closeAllWindows()
        print("closed")
        ev.accept()

class MainWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.layout = QHBoxLayout()
        self.layout.setContentsMargins(2, 2, 2, 2)
        self.layout.setSpacing(6)

        self.stepFilterDisplayWidget = StepFilterDisplayWidget()
        self.stepFilterControlWidget = StepFilterControlWidget()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.stepFilterDisplayWidget)
        self.layout.addWidget(self.stepFilterControlWidget)
        self.setLayout(self.layout)
        self.setGeometry(100,100,1000,700)

class StepFilterDisplayWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StepFilterDisplayWidget,self).__init__(*args,**kwargs)

        self.layout = QVBoxLayout()
        self.setLayout(self.layout)

        self.plot = pg.ImageView()
        self.layout.addWidget(self.plot)

        self.button = QPushButton("Plot", self)
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.showImage)

        self.layout.addWidget(self.button)

    def showImage(self):
        im = Image.open('S_15a_crop.tif')
        self.data = np.array(im)
        self.plot.setImage(self.data)


class StepFilterControlWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(StepFilterControlWidget, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    controller = MainController()
    app.exec_()
    del app
```

Comment: Just thinking - QApplication.closeAllWindows() closes the windows and  ev.accept() trying to close a closed window right? But i think segmentation fault occurs in "del app" code block at the bottom.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.

I tried commenting out all three lines you mention and the same thing happens regardless....

Comment: Interesting. When i try to run the code i get <RuntimeError: the PyQt5.QtCore and PyQt4.QtCore modules both wrap the QObject class> I dont know how did you handled this but maybe the point is about that. (i get this error because of pyqtgraph i think)

Comment: Hmmm, that's an interesting point;  I had to override a flag to get pyqtgraph installed on Sierra. Perhaps that's the problem.

Comment: Yep, when I comment out the pyqtgraph lines there is no problem anymore.

Comment: This is not really a minimal example. Could you maybe remove all the lines not needed to produce the error?

Comment: @Trilarion how does he know which lines are necesarry which ones are not in "Segmentation Fault" error?

Comment: @obayhan How does anyone know how to produce a minimal example in case of any kind of error?

Comment: @Trilarion please enlighten us which part is throwing the error. I or you may guess because we know where is the problem but he doesn't know and  asking for that.

As you can see easily there is no exception info except "segmentation fault".

Comment: @obayhan Come on. Just throw out code until the error vanishes then go one step back. This results in a minimal example. Everyone can do that regardless of any knowledge about the particular problem. What are you aiming at exactly?

Comment: @Trilarion if you investigate the problem the minimal example will make the things harder instead of solving the problem for this situation. Because the problem is not at the place where exception throws. The problem is caused by "import pyqtgraph as pg" but the exception looks thrown at ev.accept() and plus it occured in "QApplication.closeAllWindows" .But if you look at the output; "QApplication.closeAllWindows" part passed well.I am wondering 2 things.First please tell me which minimal(!) part is needed? (: Second if he knows which part is needed that means he already solved the problem (:

Comment: @obayhan I disagree. A minimal example cannot make things harder, only easier because you reduce the number of possible error sources. Knowing the location that creates problem also doesn't automatically mean you know how to solve it. In the end, StackOverflow requires a minimal example. For more information why see [How to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Comment: @Trilarion " A minimal example cannot make things harder, only easier" is a general opinion, it is true but not in this situation/example. Because as i asked earlier before he doesn't know where is the problem and he cannot find it by looking at output. I am saying again the reason of the problem is this line -> "import pyqtgraph as pg" and probably this line would'n find a place itself in minimal example .

Anyway. General opinions and habits are not always true like in this question.

Comment: @obayhan This line must be included in the minimal example, because otherwise it wouldn't be one. Minimal example means shortest possible code that reproduces the error. You may misunderstand the meaning of a minimal example. I see no disadvantages. Even this case would have benefited from a minimal example. The advantage would have been to exclude other potential sources of error. As I said, StackOverflow wants to have it always and I think with good reason. See also [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @Trilarion Depending on  "Minimal example means shortest possible code that reproduces the error." is the defination of "minimal example with same error occurence" for me not "minimal example" :) When i read all conversation again i noticed that i missed  "to produce the error" part in "Could you maybe remove all the lines not needed to produce the error?" sentence of you. We agreed then :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is about pyqtgraph (which uses PyQt4) and PyQt5 imports. pyqtgraph trying to use something belongs to PyQt4 which was overriden by PyQt5 import. This triggers the segmentation fault.

Comment: update: I upgraded to Python 3.6 from 3.5.2 and this is no longer an issue.

Comment: probably pyqtgraph is using pyqt5 in python3 or in newer version

Comment: I had same problem with python3.9 / 3.10 and pyqt + pyqtgraph installed in a conda environment --  pyqt4 was not installed.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same problem - with pyqt5 and python3.10
My app has 3 `pyqtgraph` widgets:

- 1 `pg.ImageView()` created directly in the main application which is a `QtWidgets.QMainWindow()`
- 2 `pg.PlotWidget()` + `pg.opengl.GLViewWidget()` loaded into the mainwidow application from another class `QueryBuilder()` which is `QWidget`

To quit the app I was using a call to `qApp.quit()` action. When only the `pg.ImageView()` was loaded - I had no core dump issue. The segfault issue came just after adding the `QueryBuilder()` code.
Adding, into the quit method, a call to close the QueryBuilder() widget fixed the issue

```
from querybuilder import QueryBuilder   # widgets with pyqtgraph

class MapDisplay():
    ...
    self.querybuilder = QueryBuilder()
    ...
    
    def quit(self):
        self.querybuilder.close()
        qApp.quit()
```